# How to get SessionID on a request where EnableSessionState="False"

Tags: asp.net, session-state, webmethod, sessionid

I want to be able to get the **SessionID** of the currently authenticated session in a **WebMethod** function where **EnableSession = false**.

I cannot set **EnableSession=true** on this request, because another (long running) request on a different page is keeping the **SessionState** locked (EnableSessionState == "True" not "Readonly").

Is there a consistent way of getting the **SessionID** from either the *ASP.NET Session cookie* or the *Url* for cookieless sessions? I can code it myself but I would rather use a function that is already documented and tested.

Thank you very much,
Florin.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There seems to be no ASP.NET function that can do this, so I made up a hack of my own, which works... for now ;):

```
private string GetSessionID(HttpContext context)
{
  var cookieless = context.Request.Params["HTTP_ASPFILTERSESSIONID"];
  if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(cookieless))
  {
    int start = cookieless.LastIndexOf("(");
    int finish = cookieless.IndexOf(")");
    if (start != -1 && finish != -1)
      return cookieless.Substring(start + 1, finish - start - 1);
  }
  var cookie = context.Request.Cookies["ASP.NET_SessionId"];
  if (cookie != null)
    return cookie.Value;
  return null;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

`HttpContext.Current.Session.SessionID`

Comment: Session is not available on this request, so HttpContext.Current.Session == null.