# How to get the session value from asp.net webservice

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, web-services

As in the title, How to get the `session` value from `asp.net web-service` ?

To read `Session("Id")` for example

Comment: What is a session value?

Comment: Can you explain? (more details!)

Comment: Is it duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1378352/how-to-get-sessionid-on-a-request-where-enablesessionstate-false

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean:

```
HttpContext.Current.Session.SessionID
```

(As i wrote in the comment, more info required)